# WebRTC video artifacts from iPhone X and iPhone 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, webrtc, iphone-x

I have an iOS WebRTC application (with EasyRTC wrapper). It worked with all  iOS devices until iPhone X came out.
The problem is that video *from* iPhone X on other devices looks like this:

[image: iphoneX broken video]

What changes in iPhone X cause this kind of artifacts? And how to fix it?

To start the video I'm using following code:

```
@implementation WebRTCModule (RTCMediaStream)

- (RTCMediaConstraints *)defaultMediaStreamConstraints {
    NSDictionary *mandatoryConstraints
            = @{ kRTCMediaConstraintsMinWidth     : @"1280",
                 kRTCMediaConstraintsMinHeight    : @"720",
                 kRTCMediaConstraintsMinFrameRate : @"30" };
    RTCMediaConstraints* constraints =
    [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints optionalConstraints:nil];
    return constraints;
}
typedef void (^NavigatorUserMediaErrorCallback)(NSString *errorType, NSString *errorMessage);
typedef void (^NavigatorUserMediaSuccessCallback)(RTCMediaStream *mediaStream);

- (void)getUserVideo:(NSDictionary *)constraints
    successCallback:(NavigatorUserMediaSuccessCallback)successCallback
      errorCallback:(NavigatorUserMediaErrorCallback)errorCallback
        mediaStream:(RTCMediaStream *)mediaStream {
    id videoConstraints = constraints[@"video"];
    AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice;
    if ([videoConstraints isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        for (AVCaptureDevice *aVideoDevice in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
            if (aVideoDevice.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
                videoDevice = aVideoDevice;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!videoDevice) {
            videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        }
    }
    if (videoDevice) {
        RTCMediaConstraints* constraints = [self defaultMediaStreamConstraints];
        RTCAVFoundationVideoSource *videoSource = [self.peerConnectionFactory avFoundationVideoSourceWithConstraints:constraints];

        dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.app.videoquality", 0);
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
            videoSource.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
            switch (videoDevice.position) {
                case AVCaptureDevicePositionBack:
                    if (videoSource.canUseBackCamera) {
                        videoSource.useBackCamera = YES;
                    }
                break;
                    case AVCaptureDevicePositionFront:
                    videoSource.useBackCamera = NO;
                break;
            }
            NSString *trackUUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
            RTCVideoTrack *videoTrack = [self.peerConnectionFactory videoTrackWithSource:videoSource trackId:trackUUID];
            [mediaStream addVideoTrack:videoTrack];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                successCallback(mediaStream);
            });
        });
    } else {
        errorCallback(@"OverconstrainedError", /* errorMessage */ nil);
    }
}
@end
```

My guess is `sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` doesn't work as it should in iPhone X. But unfortunately I can't check it at the moment.

---

UPD.

Same behavior is observed when transmitting video from iPhone 8.
But on iPhone 7 with iOS 11.2.1 everything works fine.

---

UPD. 2

I've disabled this custom code that sets quality but the issue is still present.

---

UPD. 3

This happens on WebRTC version 58.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same issue by set these code in iPhone X side after create videosource

```
VideoSource.adaptOutputFormat(toWidth: 1280, height: 720, fps: 30);
VideoSource.captureSession.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720);
```

I don't have 2 iPhone X to testing case not set these code.

Comment: Your second line has no side effects. And you're discarding the result. `adaptOutputFormat` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

After updating WebRTC to version 65 this issue no longer occurs. I cannot tell what was the root cause.

Even though the characteristics of the front camera remained the same (iPhone 7 has 1080p@30fps, iPhone X has 1080p@30fps) it seems like solution proposed by @Mung Bean might actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seems that active format for iPhoneX is too much for other devices to handle. Solution is to set some lower camera format:

```
cameraVideoCapturer = RTCCameraVideoCapturer(delegate: videoSource)
if let camera = RTCCameraVideoCapturer.captureDevices().filter({ $0.position == cameraPosition }).first {
   cameraVideoCapturer.startCapture(with: camera, format: camera.formats.first!, fps: 30)
}
```

Here I set first format which is the lowest for illustration but any of the 1280x720 will do the trick.